# PLD programming language panorama

Tags: programming, pld

what are the current options to program the PLD?
I'm looking for a modern, supported, open source if possible, solution to program such devices.

Comment: Have you got a list of manufacturers and device families of the PLD's you want to program? The programming options could well be manufacturer / device family specific.

Comment: There's really two layers to that. You need to describe the logic function you want in some language (PALASM, CUPL, whatever). Then you need sort of compiler/parser which converts that to a chip specific binary blob that needs to be uploaded to chip. Then you need the programmer which understands how to actually upload the binary blob to the chip.